# Avoid page refresh click on Button Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

`enter code here` NET application, I have inserted a button that call a Javascript function (OnClick event) and a asp.net function (OnClick event)
The problem is that when I click the button, it refreshes the page.
How can I avoid the page refreshes click on asp button using javascript?

```js
 document.getElementById('pageurl').innerHTML = "tryfblike.aspx";
          $('#<%= btnsave.ClientID %>').click();
          $('#auth-loggedout').hide();
```

```
<asp:Button runat="server"  ID="btnsave" OnClick="btnsave_Click();"  Visible="true" style="display: none;"  />

protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    objda.agentid = "2";
    string currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    objda.datetime = currenttime;
    ds = objda.tbl_log();
}
```

Comment: please add some code. So we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

First to call JavaScript function, use `OnClientClick`.
To avoid page refresh, after your function call add `return false;`

For example:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="Server" OnClientClick="btnsave_Click(); return false;" />
```

Comment: bt, how to execute btnsave_Click event

Comment: @aparnarai, remove `return false;` .. The `return false` is to stop hitting the server back

Comment: after remove return false, again reload the whole page, how to stop page refresh

Comment: if you want to execute server-side code then you either, 1- post back to the server; hence refresh the page, or 2- make an AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

in java script you can use return false.
if you want prevent whole page referesh use ajax.

Comment: How to execute btnsave_Click event

Comment: if you want to prevent post back on button click use client side button!

Comment: for use server data you can use ajax call from client side button.

Answer (score 0):

FirstYou can call javascrip onclick and then simply add 
return false;